# Separating text on the screen entered by the user

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page, and I have a `<textarea>` element in it. Let's also say I have a send button that displays the message on the screen. When multiple messages are sent, their position will move to below the previous message sent. New messages will be in separate containers (I made borders). I've used this code that worked. Actually, it didn't completely work. When you enter multiple messages, instead of creating a new message border with the message inside it, it puts all your text in the same element.

```js
const button = document.getElementById("sendButton");
button.addEventListener("click", displayText);

function displayText() {
  const display = document.getElementById("msg");
  const textArea = document.getElementById("enterMsg");

  display.append(
    textArea.value,
    document.createElement("br")
  );

  textArea.value = "";
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: skyblue;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

#enterMsg {
    margin-top: 34%;
    height: 130px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: darkorange;
    background-color: #d796ff;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.enterText {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: darkorange;
    background-color: #d796ff;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

#sendButton {
    margin-left: 96%;
}

#msg {
    margin-left: 80%;
    border: solid;
    border-color: #b19cd9;
    background-color: #b4ff94;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: darkorange;
}

.extraSpace {
    padding: 5px;
}

textarea::placeholder {
  color: darkorange;
}

div.centered {
    text-align: center;
    border: solid;
    border-color: blue;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.confirmButton {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Main Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="tools.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="msg" class="extraSpace"></p>
    <textarea id="enterMsg" placeholder="Enter your message here..."></textarea>
    <button id="sendButton" onclick="displayText('msg', 'enterMsg')">Send</button>
</body>
</html>
```

As I said, this code works but it puts all messages in a single element. Is there any way to make it so that a new border appears with the entered text inside it instead of putting every message into a single element?

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Main Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="tools.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="messages"></div>
    <textarea id="enterMsg" placeholder="Enter your message here..."></textarea>
    <button id="sendButton" onclick="displayText('msg', 'enterMsg')">Send</button>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
const button = document.getElementById("sendButton");
button.addEventListener("click", displayText);


const textArea = document.getElementById("enterMsg");
const container = document.getElementById("messages");
function displayText() {
  // Create a new element with the message as it's inner text.
  const message = document.createElement("p");
  message.innerText = textArea.value;
  message.setAttribute("class", "msg");

  // Add that to the document
  container.appendChild(message);

  textArea.value = "";
}
```

You'll also have to change your stylesheet because `msg` is a class now rather than an ID (since there will be more than one of them

Comment: I've changed #msg to .msg in the stylesheet but now whenever I try to enter a message, the text doesn't show up on the screen and the `<textarea>` doesn't clear. Is there any reason for this?